# Can outside images be brought by link into MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

On my personal MediaWiki site I am trying to display my StackExchange flair, but I cannot find a way to set the address to the flair on the SE itself.

Just to be clear, I know I could download the flair image itself and put it into the wiki, but since the flair changes with my activity on SE, I want the flair to reflect this activity.  Is there a way to have an image hosted on another site display in MediaWiki?  Here's what I am trying to display:

```
<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/16964.png" width="208" height="58" 
alt="profile for Cyberherbalist at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" 
title="profile for Cyberherbalist at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers">
```

Which looks like:

[image: profile for Cyberherbalist at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Can this even be done?

Answer (score 2):

There is a configuration setting called [$wgAllowExternalImages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowExternalImages) that you will need to toggle on.  Per the documentation:

> When set to true, users can bring in an inline image from an external URL. They do this simply by sticking the full URL into the wiki text (without any other surrounding markup being required) That is the direct URL to an image resource on another website.

If allowing all external images isn't something you're interested in, you may consider [$wgEnableImageWhitelist](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableImageWhitelist) instead.

Comment: Amazing.  I am going to have to read each and every one of those settings in order to get a sense of which ones might be valuable to me.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist [Read away](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:MediaWiki_configuration_settings), and configure to your heart's content -- there's certainly enough different settings to do so!